# error: pasting "->" and "object" does not give a valid preprocessing

Tags: c++, c

I have the following macro:

```
#define FIELD_ACCESSOR_FUNCTIONS(typeName, fieldAccessorNamePrefix) \
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL my_pckg_NativeExecutor_get ## typeName ## FieldValue(JNIEnv* jNIEnv, jobject nativeExecutorInstance, jobject target, jobject field) { \
    return environment-> ## fieldAccessorNamePrefix ## FieldAccessor->getValue(jNIEnv, target, field); \
}

FIELD_ACCESSOR_FUNCTIONS(Object, object)
```

And when I start the compilation I get the following error:

```
NativeExecutor.cpp:59:20: error: pasting "->" and "object" does not give a valid preprocessing token
  return environment-> ## fieldAccessorNamePrefix ## FieldAccessor->getValue(jNIEnv, target, field); \
                    ^~
```

How can I solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the first `##`. The name you are trying to generate is `fieldAccessorNamePrefix ## FieldAccessor`. The `->` must not be part of the token.